# How to find a minimal rooted tree with maximial sum vertex weights?

Tags: spanning-tree

I have an undirected grid graph, nxm, where each vertex has a value (positive or negative) and I need to find the tree rooted at vertex (1,1) that maximizes the sum of these values with a minimal number vertices.

The tree do not have to go through all nodes, although the tree can pick a negative vertex so it can pick a positive one.

Edges have no value.

I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "spanning" here? Clearly, the standard meaning makes your question nonsensical...

Comment: I think that a simple reformulation could make the question interesting albeit not very hard to answer: ask for finding the connected subgraph with maximal sum of vertex weights and minimal number of vertices.

Comment: @fedja something like this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree

Comment: @ManfredWeis Thanks. I will think about it. But I was trying to make it clear that I can not have subtours.

Comment: Once the minimal connected component with maximal sum of vertex weight is found, you can construct a spanning tree *of that component*; the sum of weights will not change because the set of vertices is the same.

Comment: @ManfredWeis It is not need to go through all the vertices: we can ignore some of them. I just want to pick the continuous path that maximize the sum and it can have dead ends (it is not like a maze). Sorry that the question is not fully clear at first.

Comment: @Sghat now I am getting confused about what you want know; do you want to maximize the sum of vertex weight  of a tree that contains $(1,1)$ or do you want to maximize the sum of vertex weights of all paths in that tree? Could you please explain in natural language, where your question comes from?

Comment: @ManfredWeis I may be confusing some of the subjects. Thank you for persisting. They have a flat underground mining area that looks like a chessboard. Each square has a benefit value (revenue - cost) that can be positive or negative. Starting from $(1,1)$ we have to pick the squares that maximize the total value of the deposit. Although this path has to be continuos (so we have access to other squares) it can have branches (when  a square is picked its benefit occurs only once). As the path has to be continuos, sometimes we have to pick a negative value so we have access to a bigger positive.

Comment: @ManfredWeis maybe it is a maximum-weight-connected-subgraph problem. What do you think?

Comment: @Sghat thanks for your explanation of the problem; so I had suspected the right thing; it is the connected subgraph that contains $(1,1)$ and has maximal sum of  vertex weights.

Comment: @ManfredWeis Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: @Sghat I will provide an algorithm this weekend; during the week my time is limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal solution can be found as follows:

- repeatedly delete from the vertices with negative weight the one, that has minimal weight and whose removal doesn't disconnect the graph, i.e. that isn't an articulation vertex.
- replace each connected component of the subgraph induced by edges, that are ajacent to two vertices with positive weight, by a single vertex and assign to it the sum of all vertex weights in that component.
- replace the paths between two vertices with positive weight by an edge, whose weight equals the sum of negative vertex weights on that path.
- in the resulting tree-graph define the vertex that "contains" $(1,1)$ as the root
- start a depth-first search from the root node:

  - after returning from descending into each of the children of a vertex $v$, either

    - add the sum of the weights $\omega(v)$ and $\omega(e)$ of $v$ and of the edge $e$ adjacent to $v$ and to $v$'s father-vertex $u$ if $\omega(v)+\omega(e)\gt 0$, i.e $\ \omega(u)=\omega(u)+\omega(e)+\omega(v)$ in that case
    - otherwise add nothing to the father-node weight and mark $e$ and $v$ as deleted
- finally replace the tree-nodes and edges that aren't marked as deleted, by the corresponding vertices and edges of the original graph to obtain the optimal solution.

Comment: You could have not helped more.
Thank you again.

I also share a Java solver that I found:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02168

https://github.com/ctlab/gmwcs-solver

Comment: @Sghat I am happy to hear that could help you; it was a nice problem I enjoyed.